# Text in div overflowing to the top and the bottom

Tags: html, css, angular

I have a problem that I can not currently solve. It's about a angular material accordion I have built, which contains a series of buttons (built from div blocks with texts). I noticed that I have problems with texts that have more than one line. The text then breaks at the end of the div, but unfortunately not down into the div container as usual, but out of the top and bottom of the div.

Now I have tried different approaches like Styling the Div with overflow methodes, adjusting the height, ... , but so far no solution found.

I would be happy about an answer, if you need more information, please let me know!

Stackblitz-Example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-side-nav-dynamic-expansive-menu-cg452o?embed=1&file=main.ts

[image]

```css
.item {
  background-color: aqua;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.category {
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  margin-top: 5px;
}
```

```html
<mat-nav-list>
  <mat-accordion>
    <mat-expansion-panel class="category">
      <mat-expansion-panel-header>
        <mat-panel-title>
          <!-- Category -->
          <div>
            Category
          </div>
        </mat-panel-title>
      </mat-expansion-panel-header>
      <mat-list-item class="item">
        <!-- Items  -->
        <div>
          <div>Item Item Item Item Item Item Item Item Item Item Item Item Item Item Item Item Item Item Item Item Item Item Item Item Item Item                    Item Item Item Item Item Item Item Item Item Item Item Item Item Item Item Item Item Item Item Item Item Item </div>
        </div>
      </mat-list-item>
    </mat-expansion-panel>
  </mat-accordion>
</mat-nav-list>
```

EDIT: Without mat-nav-list it is working, no text-overlays when resizing my browser-window, but no Styling-Access:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for explaining! I did what you suggested and put the html-code of the mat-accordion with the first generated category and it's three items in the post. I hope that helps.

Comment: You wouldn't need to include all relevant CSS, too. It obviously doesn't show your problem as it is.

Comment: No, it doesn't help much, because _all_ your snippet shows when we run it, is the text "Allgemeine Fragen" in black on white. That does not even come close to reproducing the problem. There are services like https://stackblitz.com, where you can set up a complete testing environment for stuff based on frameworks like angular, maybe give that a try.

Comment: Here, maybe this helps: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-side-nav-dynamic-expansive-menu-cg452o?embed=1&file=main.ts

The problem get's worse if you adjust your browser window horizontally.

Comment: I think I found the problem: It's the tag "mat-nav-list". When I delete this tag out of my code, I just get all the text listet among themselves. But this isn't really a solution, because now my css is not able to style the html-items anymore. (see "EDIT:..." in my post)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem occurred in connection with the "mat-list, mat-item" component provided by Angular. I thought I can solve the problem with a simple "height: auto". Unfortunately that didn't work and I started to puzzle. In the end I had to put an !important after the auto, then everything works. So the final solution is the following:

```css
.item {
  height: auto !important;
}
```

Comment: Just to note, it is a bad habit to use !important because this way, you can end up in different important flags for a single property set from different places (e.g. classes, elements, etc.). It is always better to try to find a way without using !important.